# How to define coordinate points inside texts in tikz?

Tags: latex, tikz

I have created this image in LaTeX:

```
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
\tikzmath{ \w = 6; \h =4; \x = 2; }
\draw [fill=gray!30,thick] (-\w/2,-\h/2) rectangle (\w/2,\h/2);
\draw [->,thick] (\w/2, 0) -- (\w/2+\x,0);
\draw [->,thick] (-\w/2-\x, 0) -- (-\w/2,0);
\node [left] at (-\w/2-\x,0) {Input};
\node [right] at (\w/2+\x, 0) {Output};
\node [align=left,font=\ttfamily] at (0,0) {\small function(...) \{\\...\\\}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

#### Desired effect

What I want to achieve is the following:

[image]

As you can see, the input arrow will have to point to the middle of what's inside the brackets in text `function (...)`. And the output arrow will have to start from the end of the middle line.

It all gets down to defining points or coordinates inside the text. How can I tell tikz to create a coordinate exactly inside text `function (<HERE>)`?

I am expecting to be able to write something in those positions:

```
\node [align=left,font=\ttfamily] at (0,0) {\small function(<HERE>) \{\\...<HERE>\\\}};
```

How?

Comment: Dear reviewers, this is a pure tex problem and unrelated to programming. I think it would be best if it would be migrated to tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: @samcarter: I understand. How can I migrate it? Do I just copy that? Or is there an automatic procedure?

Comment: @ Andry You don't need to do anything. I flagged the question to be migrated and reviewers will have a look at it. If enough of them agree, the question will automatically be migrated.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what the `tikzmark` package is made for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7,overlay, remember picture]
\tikzmath{ \w = 6; \h =4; \x = 2; }
\draw [fill=gray!30,thick] (-\w/2,-\h/2) rectangle (\w/2,\h/2);
\draw [->,thick] (\w/2, 0) -- (\w/2+\x,0);
\draw [->,thick] (-\w/2-\x, 0) -- (-\w/2,0);
\node [left] at (-\w/2-\x,0) {Input};
\node [right] at (\w/2+\x, 0) {Output};
\node [align=left,font=\ttfamily] at (0,0) {\small function(..\tikzmark{foo}.) \{\\...\\\}};

\draw[blue,-latex] (-3*\w/4,0) -| (-3*\w/4,0.3*\h) -| (pic cs:foo) ; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

edit:

for me the code works fine with pdflatex from texlive2019 using the following package versions:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
     pgf.sty    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
  pgffor.sty    2019/05/09 v3.1.3 (3.1.3)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
   expl3.sty    2019-05-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-05-09 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
l3keys2e.sty    2019-05-03 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
  xparse.sty    2019-05-03 L3 Experimental document command parser
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: This seems good and I tried it but I get this: 

>! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.
>See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

Comment: @Andry Did you try with the exact same code as in my answer or with your real document? If the exact same code as in my answer does not work, your packages might not be up-to-date, check if your tex distribution is up-to-date.

Comment: Yes I tried the same code. I will try and see what's wrong with my Tex...

Comment: @Andry For comparison I added the package versions I'm using